# How to alter scripts to pull API data

Tags: api, curl

I am trying to pull data from the below 3rd party API.

```
curl --request GET \
 --url 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages?limit=1000&query=last_event_time%20BETWEEN%20TIMESTAMP%20%22{start_date}%22%20AND%20TIMESTAMP%20%22{end_date}%22' \
 --header 'authorization: Bearer <<your API key>>'
```

The problem I am having is the API has a max limit of 1000 rows. How could I workaround this as I already have the data filters in place but my expected output is around 30k

Comment: aaaaah that `--request GET` in there makes me wanna cry, please remove it!

Comment: The explanation for my comment above has been done many times but I also blogged it years ago here: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/